# Issues with Microsoft Graph API Emails retrieve

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I want to use the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve incoming messages to certain email. Here is the current implementation:

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{$tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
$token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
  'form_params' => [
  'client_id' => $clientId,
  'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
  'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
  'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
]])->getBody()->getContents());

$accessToken = $token->access_token;
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Retrieve the emails
$messages = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/users/{$emailAddress}/messages")
->setReturnType(Model\Message::class)
->execute();

return $messages;
```

I get the access token without an issue but when I try to run the messages query I keep getting error 403:

> "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.".

I have all permissions set. I tried running the query through MS Graph Explorer and it works, but when I try to run it in PHP it doesn't.

Comment: Does the app you're connecting with have permission to read that mailbox?

Comment: _"I tried running the query through MS Graph Explorer and it works."_ - with that very same access token, that your script here is using ...?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the permissions I had assigned to the application were "Delegated" - that means the user had to log in via the frontend in Microsoft to have full access to them. I had to choose the "Application" type for the permissions - this way they are available in the access token.